# Using if else with jsp from data-bind

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement, data-binding

so I don't really know how to describe my question the best way since I never worked in jsp before, and I just jumped in another project and needs to finish it.

Sorry if this is unclear, just ask me anything and I'll try do reply fast.

So they got a language check for some html tags, which looks like this:

```
<p data-bind="if: 'en_US' == currentLang()">english text</p>
```

which works fine, but I want to put this in an if/else statement.

In PHP, I would write something like:

```
<?php if((currentLang() == 'en_US)) {
    echo 'english text';
else {
    echo 'italian text';
}
?>
```

so how do I do this, checking currentLang() in my .jsp file?

Comment: See JSTL tags for more details

Comment: The HTML you pasted looks like it might be for the [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html) client-side JavaScript framework or similar. This is unlikely to be evaluated by server-side JSPs.

Comment: Right. Knockout IS installed. So there's no way I can check which language is selected?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the f:subview Tag (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/subview.html) and put your condition in the rendered attribute

```
<f:subview rendered="if: 'en_US' == currentLang()">english text
</f:subview>
```

I think this should work.